# How to add an item in an array FROM a specific index-Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm looking to insert an element from index 1 of an array:

```
 render() {
  if (some condition) {
      let rules = [{label:"a"},{label:"b"},{label:"c"},{label:"d"}];
      let data = [];
      rules.forEach((rule) => {

          data.push(
            <div>
              {//some condition to true  &&
                <label>OR</label>}  //this OR should be added only from the 1st index of the array

                <ComboBox
                  placeholder= "Select a token ..."
                  value={someval}
                  listItems={list} />
            </div>)

      });


  return data;
}
```

}

The above will be pushed for all "true" conditions, but I need to push another element only from beginning of index 1 of an array. In short only the first element in the array should have this element. Something like:

```
if (some condition)
 {
   data.push(
       <span>Test</span><div><span>A</span></div>
)
}
```

At the end, should look something like: https://jsfiddle.net/w42hke3h/

How can do this? Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: This is confusing.  Your fiddle contains no JS code.  I have no idea what you're trying to do.

Comment: Are you looking for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice?

Comment: Can you try to explain by adding a scenario with multiple iterations in order to show what is exactly needed?

Comment: So Lets say I have an initial array arr=["a","b","c","d","e"].Now on certain condition I'd like to prefix an element from index 1 of the array: https://jsfiddle.net/w42hke3h/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use unshift. It works exactly like push but adds the element to the front of the array.

```
let rules = [{label:"a"},{label:"b"},{label:"c"},{label:"d"}];
let data = [];

rules.forEach(() => {
   if (some condition) {
     data.unshift(...);
   }   
)};
```